# How to loop event click the get the attributes of each a?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I want to get the value of the `data-id` of each a property of the `onclick` click event, but the click does not respond and does not get the value of each property.
Do you have any way to click on each attribute?

**Please take a look at my code:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var showClick = document.getElementById("showClick");
  for (var i = 0; i < showClick.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      showClick[i].onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventdefault()
        alert(showClick.getAttribute("data-id"));
      }
    })(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="showClick" href="" data-id="1">dd</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="showClick" href="" data-id="2">ee</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="showClick" href="" data-id="3">gg</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="showClick" href="" data-id="4">xx</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `id` attribute is supposed to be unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fo all the `id` attribute **must** be unique. Use common classes instead like :

```
<li>
    <a class="showClick" href="" data-id="1">dd</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="showClick" href="" data-id="2">ee</a>
</li>
```

It will be better to use `.addEventListener()` to attach the `click` event.

**NOTE:** It's more efficient to use `dataset` when you deal with `data-* attributes` like :

```
this.dataset.id
```

To get the `data-id` attribute.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var showClick = document.querySelectorAll(".showClick");

  for (var i = 0; i < showClick.length; i++) {
    showClick[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      console.log(this.dataset.id);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="showClick" href="" data-id="1">dd</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="showClick" href="" data-id="2">ee</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="showClick" href="" data-id="3">gg</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="showClick" href="" data-id="4">xx</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad I could help brother.

Comment: *should be unique* should be ***must** be unique*. This is not optional.

Comment: Go ahead and replace it in the answer @connexo

Comment: Thanks for your intervention :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `id` attribute should be unique over all the elements. Since there should only ever be 1 element with an Id the method `getElementById` returns only a single item. In this case probably the first the element in the DOM with the ID.

If you want to be able to get multiple elements from the DOM you're probably better off assigning them a CSS class. To indicate that the class is used to find elements in the DOM people sometimes prefix these class with something like `js-`. A good way to get multiple elements at once is to use `querySelectorAll`. It will match elements in the DOM given a CSS selector. For your case it would work like this:

```js
function onShowClickElementClicked(event) {
  var showClickElement = event.currentTarget;
  
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('You clicked an element with ID: ', showClickElement.getAttribute("data-id"));
}

window.onload = function () {
    var showClickElements = document.querySelectorAll(".js-showClick");
    for (var i = 0; i < showClickElements.length; i++) {
      showClickElements[i].addEventListener('click', onShowClickElementClicked);
    }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
}
button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <button class="js-showClick" type="button" data-id="1">dd</button>
  </li>
  <li>
      <button class="js-showClick" type="button" data-id="2">ee</button>
  </li>
  <li>
      <button class="js-showClick" type="button" data-id="3">gg</button>
  </li>
  <li>
      <button class="js-showClick" type="button" data-id="4">xx</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Side note: If you want an interactive element (like an element which will receive tab focus) but which shouldn't navigate to a different page, you're almost always best off using a `button` element.